# isAttachedToWindow() alternative for API level < 19

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-windowmanager

I want to use the call `videoView.isAttachedToWindow()` within my fragment to verify if videoview is initialized fine and is ready to be called.

But this call requires api level 19 (current min is 14). What is the best alternative for `videoView.isAttachedToWindow()` for API level 14 and above?

EDIT: My videoview plays video streamed through HDMI input of Android boxes. In certain hardware that has OS 4.0.4, videoview sometimes jitter.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`ViewCompat.isAttachedToWindow()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#isAttachedToWindow(android.view.View)) will do the trick up to API 4.